# How can I click a floating advertisement?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I'm trying to move to a different page (click 'my account'), and a floating advertisement appears:
[advertisement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYbk3.png)

I tried to click on it, and can't find the "Close" element.
Found that it might related to frames, but still not works.

My Code:

```
public void clickMyAccount() {
    driver.findElement(myAccountBtn).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void clickCloseAd(){
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("google_esf")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("aswift_9")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ad_iframe")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("dismiss-button")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Site:
https://practice.automationtesting.in/

Any idea how can I click the floating advertisement?

Tried: move between frames until able to find the Close element
Actual: still can't find this element

Comment: How to make the ad to show up? It don't appear in any browser.

Comment: Hi pburgr, I'm able to see the ad only in the chromedriver browser

Comment: in my case even in chromedriver the ad doesn't show up.

Comment: Wierd, 90% of the times when I click on "My Account" via the chromedriver it's showing me the ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

1. My 'wait' not always working, so the driver tries to close the ad when not displayed - still searching for a way to correct this
2. It's working without frame1: "google_esf", only frame2 and frame3 needed

Updated code:

```
        public void clickMyAccount() {
        System.out.println("Click My Account");

        if(driver.findElement(myAccountBtn).isDisplayed()){
            driver.findElement(myAccountBtn).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        } else {
            System.out.println("My account button not displayed");
        }

    }

    public void clickCloseAd(){
        System.out.println("Click Close Ad");


            if(driver.findElement(By.id("aswift_9")).isDisplayed()){
//                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("google_esf"))); //Not in use but also a frame
                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("aswift_9")));
                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ad_iframe")));
                driver.findElement(By.id("dismiss-button")).click();

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ad not displayed");
            }
    }
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to handle advertisement popUp. So we can handle it in 2 ways:

1. downloading ad-blocker extension to your chrome and using the chrome option code.

- download ad-bocker- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom
- use chromeoption driver code:
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");

2. Notice that popUp gets disabled is do back. so we can is click on myaccount go back and then click back:

   ```
        WebElement MyAccount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@href='https://practice.automationtesting.in/my-account/']"));
    MyAccount.click();
    driver.navigate().back();
    MyAccount.click();
   ```

Comment: Thanks Fouzan Jafri, these two options seem that skip the advertisement,
But I am still trying to search for a way to handle this popUp, 
I can't understand what is wrong in my code, I'm switching to each frame of the advertisement and I can't click the "dismiss-button"